# Using option for sty file

Tags: packages, package-options, kvoptions

I would like to create and option (namely `grid`) to my `sty` file to produce a grid covering the whole page.

I had success using

```
\newif\if@sigur@grid
\DeclareOption{grid}{\@sigur@gridtrue}
```

and using the code below, which I copied from somewhere here on SE, inside some blocks of codes.

```
\if@sigur@grid
  \IfFileExists{tikz.sty}
    {\RequirePackage{tikz}%
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}%
    \usepackage{eso-pic}%
    }
    {\PackageWarning{sigur}{You requested `tikz.sty' %MessageBreak 
    which doesn't exist on your system}
    }
    \AtBeginDocument{
     \AddToShipoutPicture{%
     \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
     \draw[red!30!white]
                 (current page.south west) grid[step=1mm]
                 (current page.north east);
     \draw[red!80!white]
                 (current page.south west) grid[step=10mm]
                 (current page.north east);
     \end{tikzpicture} 
     }
     }
\fi
```

Well, this is fine and it is working. I simply load my `sty` file with the option `grid` and the red grid appears.

**Now here comes my problem.** As you can see the grid was drawn in red color. I'd like to be able to pass its color to the `grid` option when loading it. For example, the default color is red but if I want blue grid I'd simply use `grid=blue` as option and the grid would appear in blue color.

How to do this?

**ps:** I'd like to test first if some additional package is installed. I'm doing this for other packages using `\IfFileExists{}` and it is working. But I'm not able to do this for the solution proposed by @cgnieder below.

The reason for the test is that sometimes I share this style file with other users and I'd like to inform them with some option is not working instead of just show many errors caused by the missing packages.

Comment: We do not usually put the `Thanks in advance`, right? Remember?

Comment: @azetina, edited.

Answer (score 5):

The [`pgfopts`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfopts) is a convenient way of using `pgf`'s keys as package options. Here's an example where

```
\usepackage{sigur}
```

does not draw a grid,

```
\usepackage[grid]{sigur}
```

draws the default red grid, and

```
\usepackage[grid=green]{sigur}
```

draws a green grid.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}% be careful not to overwrite your actual package!
\begin{filecontents}{sigur.sty}
\ProvidesPackage{sigur}[2013/11/09 v0.0 a sample package]

\newif\if@sigur@grid
\newcommand*\sigur@grid@color{red}

\IfFileExists{pgfopts.sty}{% only if `pgfopts' is available
\RequirePackage{pgfopts}

\pgfkeys{
  sigur/.cd ,
    grid/.code =
      \@sigur@gridtrue
      \renewcommand*\sigur@grid@color{##1} ,
    grid/.default = red % if no value is given
}

\ProcessPgfOptions{/sigur}
}{% else
\DeclareOption{grid}{\@sigur@gridtrue}
\ProcessOptions*\relax
}

\if@sigur@grid
  \RequirePackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
  \RequirePackage{eso-pic}
  \AtBeginDocument{%
    \AddToShipoutPicture{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
        \draw[\sigur@grid@color!30!white]
          (current page.south west) grid[step=1mm]
          (current page.north east);
        \draw[\sigur@grid@color!80!white]
          (current page.south west) grid[step=10mm]
          (current page.north east);
      \end{tikzpicture}
    }%
  }
\fi
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[grid=green]{sigur}
\begin{document}
foo
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm trying to adjust your code to test first if the package `pgfopts` is installed. I'm using `\IfFileExists{pgfopts.sty}
    {\RequirePackage{pgfopts}%
    \pgfkeys{
      sigur/.cd ,
        grid/.code =
          \@sigur@gridtrue
          \renewcommand*\sigur@grid@color{#1} ,
        grid/.default = red % if no value is given
    }
    \ProcessPgfOptions{/sigur}
    }
    {\PackageWarning{sigur}{You requested 'pgfopts.sty' %MessageBreak 
    which doesn't exist on your system}
    }` but I'm getting errors.

Comment: Let me guess: `! Illegal parameter number in definition of`? If that's the case you need to double the `#`: `\renewcommand*\sigur@grid@color{##1}`

Comment: No, `\RequirePackage or \LoadClass in Options Section.`

Comment: @Sigur that's unrelated to the `\IfFileExists` addition. Do you still have a `\ProcessOptions` in addition to `\ProcessPgfOptions` or something? (This is only random guesswork, of course...)

Comment: Should I use both `ProcessPgfOptions` and `\ProcessOptions`?

Comment: @Sigur No. However, I cannot reproduce your issue, see edited answer

Comment: Hum... the first error is still `\RequirePackage or \LoadClass in Options Section. }` and then `Undefined control sequence }` and many others. I have other options on my file. I'll see if I have the `pgfopts` package.

Comment: @sigur You should boil down your actual file to a MWE: this will either reveal what's causing it or you can ask a follow-up question.

Comment: I discovered what is the problem. If I comment all other options and leave only commands related with `grid` option, it works! But since I have other `\newif\if` and `\DeclareOption` the problem appears. I guess that it is related with the `\ProcessOptions`. How to process the others with I'm using the command inside the `IfFileExists`?

Comment: @Sigur If they're all just `\newif\if@sigure@foo\DeclareOption{foo}{\@sigure@footrue}` you can declare them as `pgf` keys: `\newif\if@sigur@foo\pgfkeys{sigur/foo/.is if = @sigure@foo}` (before `\ProcessPgfOptions`). (This actually sounds like a follow-up question)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now it is time to study `pgfkeys` to make it work.

Answer (score 5):

Since your question is tagged [kvoptions](/questions/tagged/kvoptions), here's an answer using that package.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{sigur.sty}
\ProvidesPackage{sigur}[2013/11/09 v0.0 a sample package]

\RequirePackage{kvoptions}

\newif\ifsigur@grid
\DeclareStringOption{grid}[red]
\AddToKeyvalOption*{grid}{\sigur@gridtrue}

\ProcessKeyvalOptions*

\ifsigur@grid
  \RequirePackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
  \RequirePackage{eso-pic}
  \AtBeginDocument{%
    \AddToShipoutPicture{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
        \draw[\sigur@grid!30!white]
          (current page.south west) grid[step=1mm]
          (current page.north east);
        \draw[\sigur@grid!80!white]
          (current page.south west) grid[step=10mm]
          (current page.north east);
      \end{tikzpicture}
    }%
  }
\fi
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[grid=green]{sigur}
%\usepackage[grid]{sigur}
%\usepackage{sigur}
\begin{document}
foo
\end{document}
```

I've added three possible calls to the `sigur` package. The optionless one will not draw any grid (but the `.aux` file should be removed before processing if the option `grid` had been specified in a previous run).